# How to find out the document root or find out actual path of a URL in cPanel server?

Tags: shell, hosting, cpanel

First of all, I searched in Google to my level best to find the answer and not able to even get some clue on this.

I want to find out the actual path in the server for a given URL. I have root access. 
For example, I want to write a script, It takes URL as a input and prints the actual path in the server.

```
Example Input:  some.com/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/media/js/file.php
                abcd.com/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpgallery/img/xml.php      

The output should be
/home/some/public_html/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/media/js/file.php
/home/abcd/public_html/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpgallery/img/xml.php
```

The domain name can be add-on, or sub-domain , But it is hosted on the same server.

I want to write a shell script to achieve this. Please guide me.

I want this to be done using Linux shell script only and not using PHP.

Comment: Sorry, I was about to Inform that, I want this to be done using Linux shell script only and not using PHP.

Comment: PHP can be run from shell also using `wget` or `curl`

Comment: Thanks, But, I do not have access to edit this "some.com/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/media/js/file.php", I can only know the URL.

Comment: Just this string `some.com/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/media/js/file.php` won't give you any information like actual `DocumentRoot` or full filesystem script path.

Answer (score 1):

There is a perl based cPanel API for getting this information. Without that, It is very tough to implement it or i have not seen any code on Internet. So I dropped this.

Answer (score 0):

From any PHP code running in browser you can use:

```
# prints DocumentRoot path
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];

# prints full filesystem path of the script
echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"];
```